# php array select a Key Value in multiple arrays and change them

Tags: php, arrays

is there a simple solution I can put inside a function to resolve the following:

I have multiple arrays as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100_1
[2] => 1
[3] => 1184
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100_2
[2] => 2
[3] => 1185
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100_3
[2] => 3
[3] => 1186
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 101_2
[2] => 2
[3] => 1188
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 302
[2] => 0
[3] => 1161
[4] => 0
)
```

What I'd like to do is to select all the values which have _1,2,3 only,
and remove the _1,2,3 so the desired result would be:

```
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 1
[3] => 1184
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 2
[3] => 1185
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 3
[3] => 1186
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 101
[2] => 2
[3] => 1188
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 302
[2] => 0
[3] => 1161
[4] => 0
)
```

Notice only values which contain _1,2,3 have been changed.
Many thanks for your help it's much appreciated.

The code I have so far is:

```
foreach($data as $line) {
    if(substr($line,0,1)=="A") {
    if(!$first) {
        $parts = explode(chr(9), $line);            
        list($num1, $num2) = explode('_', $parts[1]); //this code needs to come first
        $parts[2] = isset($num2) ? $num2 : $parts[2]; //it replaces key[2] with _* (1,2,3)

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($parts); echo "</pre>";

   //the code to remove _* needs to go here.

    $pos = strpos($parts[1], '_');  // this was all it needed a simple two liner
    if($pos !== false) $parts[1] = substr($parts[1], 0, $pos);
```

Comment: How about you try first and come with a particular issue?

Comment: I have been all day - I made edits. I would say that 'Machavity' is the closest which I will test shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `_1` etc. always happens in `array[1]`

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    $pos = strpos($row[1], '_');
    if($pos !== false) $row[1] = substr($row[1], 0, $pos);
}
```

Comment: Hello Machavity this is so dam close :      $pos = strpos($parts[1], '_');
    if($pos !== false) $parts[1] = substr($parts[1], 0, $pos - 1); But it removes a '0' so key [1] shows 10 but should show 100 etc

Comment: Its ok the last $pos - 1; needs to be $pos -0; now it works great :)

Comment: Machavity can you go to my profile and there's 1 unanswered question I think you can help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

```
function formatArray($array)
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {
            $array[$key] = str_replace('_1', '', $value);
            $array[$key] = str_replace('_2', '', $value);
            $array[$key] = str_replace('_3', '', $value);
        }
        return $array;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Call this function with every array as parameter or you can assign the complete array to and parent array and then add one more `foreach` to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a function which uses preg_replace to alter your data:

```
<?php
$test_data = array("A", "100_1", "0", "1184", "0");

function removeValuesWithUnderScore(array $arr){
    //Loop over array
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        $arr[$key] = preg_replace('/_[1-3]/', '', $value);
    }

    //Return altered array
    return $arr;
}

$test_data = removeValuesWithUnderScore($test_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$array = array("A", "100_1", 0, 1184, 0);
$array = array_map(
    function($str) {
        return preg_replace('/\_[\d]+/', '', $str);
    },
    $array
);

print_r($array)
```

**Edit : If OP needs only _1, _2 and _3 to be removed :**

```
$array = array("A", "100_3", 0, 1184, 0);
$array = array_map(
    function($str) {
        return preg_replace('/\_[1|2|3]/', '', $str);
    },
    $array
);

print_r($array)
```

Comment: Would not work as he said, only _1, _2 and _3 should be removed.

Comment: @kevdev : Can you explain that?

Comment: @kevdev : Ok I got it :)

Comment: "What I'd like to do is to select all the values which have _1,2,3 only, and remove the _1,2,3" the op tells us in his question he want to remove _1,2,3 (_1,_2,_3) only, if this is not a mistake (Could also be, but the text says otherwise) your code will also remove for example _4, _5, _6 and so on.

Comment: Why do you use double pipes?

This will also remove "_|" for example.

Comment: @kevdev : Ohh sorry got confused :)

Comment: it was oh so simple in the end!

Answer (score 0):

presuming you want any value with _xxx appended to be replaced:

```
foreach($array as &$element){
    $element = strstr($element, '_', true)?:$element;
}
```